# ANTLR4 book, calculator exercise

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am stuck at a very fundamental level with antlr. Going through 'The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference' by Dr. Parr. In section 4.2, 'Building a Calculator Using a Visitor' the following grammar is listed:

```
grammar LabeledExpr; // rename to distinguish from Expr.g4

prog:   stat+ ;

stat:   expr NEWLINE                # printExpr
    |   ID '=' expr NEWLINE         # assign
    |   NEWLINE                     # blank
    ;

expr:   expr op=('*'|'/') expr      # MulDiv
    |   expr op=('+'|'-') expr      # AddSub
    |   INT                         # int
    |   ID                          # id
    |   '(' expr ')'                # parens
    ;

MUL :   '*' ; // assigns token name to '*' used above in grammar
DIV :   '/' ;
ADD :   '+' ;
SUB :   '-' ;
ID  :   [a-zA-Z]+ ;      // match identifiers
INT :   [0-9]+ ;         // match integers
NEWLINE:'\r'? '\n' ;     // return newlines to parser (is end-statement signal)
WS  :   [ \t]+ -> skip ; // toss out whitespace
```

I'm trying to add `clear` statement to the above, from the book:

Before moving on, you might take a moment to try to extend this expression language  by  adding  a `clear` statement.  The `clear` command should clear out the `memory` map, and you’ll need a new alternative in rule `stat` to recognize it. Label the alternative with `# clear` and then run `ANTLR` on the grammar to get the  augmented  visitor  interface.

This is my attempt:

```
grammar LabeledExpr;

prog:   stat+ ;

stat:   expr NEWLINE          # printExpr
    |   ID '=' expr NEWLINE   # assign
    |   clear NEWLINE         # clearMem
    |   NEWLINE               # blank
    ;

expr:   expr op=('*'|'/') expr   # MulDiv
    |   expr op=('+'|'-') expr   # AddSub
    |   INT                   # int
    |   ID                    # id
    |   '(' expr ')'          # parens
    ;

clear:  CLEAR               
    ;

MUL:    '*' ;   // assigns token name to '*' used above in grammar
DIV:    '/' ;
ADD:    '+' ;
SUB:    '-' ;

ID  :   [a-zA-Z]+ ;
INT :   [0-9]+ ;
NEWLINE: '\r'?'\n' ;
WS  :   [ \t]+ -> skip ;
CLEAR:  'clear';
```

However, `visitClearMem` never gets called:

```
@Override
public Integer visitClearMem(LabeledExprParser.ClearMemContext ctx) {
    String text = ctx.getText();
    if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("clear")) {
        memory.clear();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know this is over 3 years old, but can you post how you fixed it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the location of the `CLEAR` rule in your lexer. Since the input `clear` matches both the rules `ID` and `CLEAR`, ANTLR chooses the one that appears first in the grammar. In this case, the input `clear` becomes an `ID`.

In general, you want to place all keywords for your language before the rule for other identifiers, to ensure that they are properly matched.

Answer (score 0):

As explained by Sam Harwell, just move up the rule CLEAR: 'clear'; before the ID rule and it works and a minor modification to the code

```
@Override
public Integer visitClearMem(LabeledExprParser.ClearMemContext ctx) {
    String text = ctx.getText();
    if (text.contains("clear")) {
        memory.clear();
    }
    return 0;
}
```